# How to read headers which holds encryption meta data from kafka message using node JS

Tags: node.js, encryption, apache-kafka, avro

I am using Avro schema to read the records from kafka message. Also, Kafka message has headers. I am not sure how to read them using node js.

I wanna read encryption meta data for my decryption. How to read them using node js ?  Is it possible to read using Avro Schema?

Comment: It'd be great if you could show your attempts so far and/or mention what libraries you're using. What does your Avro schema look like?

Comment: I cant share schema directly here.  But I can say that "avsc" library is used for the schema. In the question I have pasted the sample kafka message. lets consider whole message as record. where I applied schema for record.value and I dont know how to handle the record.headers

Answer (score 0):

To read the headers from kafka message we can read it directly instead of through the Avro Schema.
For the above example:
myobj.headers[0]
myobj.headers[0]['fieldname'] worked for me.